# How to limit the number of reconnections on an activemq instance

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a spring JMS application that interacts with an activemq broker. If the application can't reach the broker, it retries indefinitely. How can I configure the activemq.xml file, or soemthing in my `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` bean so that it doesn't retry indefinitely?

I see references to an activemq ReconnectionPolicy, but i'm not sure how that gets set in the activemq.xml or if it can be set in the JMS container factory

Answer (score 3):

at the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory level you can set that like this :

```
            FixedBackOff fbo = new FixedBackOff(); // or ExponentialBackOff
            fbo.setMaxAttempts(10);
            fbo.setInterval(5000);
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory djlcf = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
            djlcf.setBackOff(fbo);
```

at the `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.setBackOff(BackOff)` too

**UPDATE**

you can use FailoverTransport only by changing the url on the

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://host:61617)?maxReconn‌​ectAttempts=10");
```

take a look at [activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to set this at the server level that would apply to all clients, or is this a per client setting?

Comment: This is a spring config and behavior and it is not affected by AMQ configs... it is better to set that at the client level

Comment: maybe if you want easiest setting you can use `FailoverTransport` only by changing the url on the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://host:61617)?maxReconnectAttempts=Value")`   take a look http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: OK, it's not clear from the defintion on how to set multiple values, is it:
failover:(tcp://host:61617)?maxRe‌​connectAttempts=111&maxReconnectDelay=2000

Comment: yes your parameters are good, all fields of FailoverTransport can be set on the url as you done

Answer (score 2):

Set a `BackOff` on the listener container factory.

```
/**
 * Specify the {@link BackOff} instance to use to compute the interval
 * between recovery attempts. If the {@link BackOffExecution} implementation
 * returns {@link BackOffExecution#STOP}, this listener container will not further
 * attempt to recover.
 * <p>The {@link #setRecoveryInterval(long) recovery interval} is ignored
 * when this property is set.
 * @since 4.1
 */
```

An `ExponentialBackOff` will increase the times between attempts, a custom `BackOff` can return `BackOffExecution.STOP` and the container will `stop()` itself. The `FixedBackOff` can be configured with `maxAttempts`.

You can also call `stop()` on the container registry (or an individual container obtained from the registry using its `id`).

Comment: Could you please provide some example of exponentialBackOff and BackOff?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in old comments; ask a new question instead. See the javadocs for the respective classes. `new FixedBackOff(5_000L, 5)` will try up to 5 times every 5 seconds then give up. new `ExponentialBackOff(1_000L, 2.0)` will try at `1, 2, 4, 8, ...` seconds. You can call `setMaxInterval` to limit the maximum back off.

Comment: This was less of a new question and more of a, "It would be very good to qualify what you are saying with an example". And thank you, that clarifies.

Comment: Understood. While maybe nor relevant here, I don't like answering comments on 3+ year answers because 3 years is a long time and software changes; the answer might be different now. Furthermore, asking supplemental questions in comments doesn't help other people searching for questions/answers on this site.